# Camping/tent facility in Prague

Tags: camping, prague

Is there any camping facility in Prague where I do not need to carry my own camping stuff and where I can borrow (with fee) a tent? or is there any existing camping place where I can stay the night?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1) [Camping Sokol Praha](http://www.campingsokol.cz/en/moznosti-ubytovani/) offers "mobile homes" for 40-60`EUR` per night

[image]]

2) [Camping Praha Klanovice](http://www.campingpraha.cz/luxury-rental-bungalow-and-tunnel-tents/) offers "bungalows" fot 50-100`EUR` per night

[image]